# Remove a particular table DOMXPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have this code and remove a given td with DOMXPath

```
$html = file_get_contents('WebProxy.html');
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->validateOnParse = true;
@$xml->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$table =$xpath->query("//*[@id='proxylisttable']")->item(0);

// for printing the whole html table just type: print $xml->saveXML($table); 

$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $cells = $row -> getElementsByTagName('td');
  foreach ($cells as $cell) {
        echo $cell->nodeValue. . '<br>';
  }
}
```

I would remove td3, TD6, td7, td8 as do that

WebProxy.html

```
td1: <td class=" ">116.226.187.242</td>
td2: <td class=" ">1080</td>
td3: <td class=" ">CN</td>
td4: <td class=" ">China</td>
td5: <td class=" ">Socks4</td>
td6: <td class=" ">Anonymous</td>
td7: <td class=" ">Yes</td>
td8: <td class=" ">1 minute ago</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
td1: <td class=" ">23.254.153.205</td>
td2: <td class=" ">60088</td>
td3: <td class=" ">US</td>
td4: <td class=" ">United States</td>
td5: <td class=" ">Socks5</td>
td6: <td class=" ">Anonymous</td>
td7: <td class=" ">Yes</td>
td8: <td ctd1: lass=" ">1 minute ago</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
td1: <td class=" ">46.101.208.9</td>
td2: <td class=" ">1080</td>
td3: <td class=" ">DE</td>
td4: <td class=" ">Germany</td>
td5: <td class=" ">Socks4</td>
td6: <td class=" ">Anonymous</td>
td7: <td class=" ">Yes</td>
td8: <td class=" ">1 minute ago</td>
</tr>
```

To be this:

```
116.226.187.242
    1080
    China
    Socks4
```

...

How could I do that, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adjust your xpath query with excluding the cells that you don't want.

For example:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('WebProxy.html');
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->validateOnParse = true;
@$xml->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$cells =$xpath->query("//*[@id='proxylisttable']/tr/td[position() != 3 and position() != 6 and position() != 7 and position() != 8]");

foreach ($cells as $cell) {
    echo $cell->nodeValue . "<br>";
}
```